# How to generate end tag for empty element in XML using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, java-6

I'm generating XML using JAXB. But JAXB is generating an empty Tag closing it self. But my client want separate empty tag. I know both are equals but he is not agree with me. please any one suggest the solution. Thanks.

Sample code:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "currencyCode",
    "discountValue",
    "setPrice",
    "spendLowerThreshold",
    "spendUpperThreshold",
    "discountApportionmentPercent",
    "discountApportionmentValue"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "countryData")
public class CountryData {
    protected String currencyCode;
    protected String discountValue = "";
    protected String setPrice = "";
    protected String spendLowerThreshold = "";
    protected String spendUpperThreshold = "";
    protected String discountApportionmentPercent = "";
    protected String discountApportionmentValue = "";

    // Setters and Gettres
}
```

Actual Output:

```
<currencyCode>GBP</currencyCode>
<discountValue/>
<setPrice/>
<spendLowerThreshold/>
<spendUpperThreshold/>
<discountApportionmentPercent>0.0</discountApportionmentPercent>
<discountApportionmentValue/>
```

Expected Output:

```
<currencyCode>GBP</currencyCode>
<discountValue></discountValue>
<setPrice></setPrice>
<spendLowerThreshold></spendLowerThreshold>
<spendUpperThreshold></spendUpperThreshold>
<discountApportionmentPercent>0.0</discountApportionmentPercent>
<discountApportionmentValue></discountApportionmentValue>
```

Code for Marshalling:

```
try {
    Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(CountryData.class).createMarshaller();
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    marshaller.marshal(countryData , os);
    log.debug("The PPV request raw XML -> " + os.toString());
} catch (JAXBException e) {
    // nothing to do
}
```

I'm Using JDK 6.0

Comment: just add an empty String in the content using @XmlValue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have generated Classes from [XSD](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema) then you would also generated ObjectFactory class. If don't please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442312/jaxb-how-do-i-generate-objectfactory-class) about how to generate ObjectFactory class.

After that, your code would be like--

```
JAXBContext context;
            context = JAXBContext.newInstance(*yourClass*.class);

final ObjectFactory objFactory = new ObjectFactory();

            final JAXBElement<YourClass> element = objFactory
                    .*autoGeneratedmethodfromObjectFactorytogetelement*;

Marshaller marshaller;
            marshaller = context.createMarshaller();

            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,
                    Boolean.TRUE);
            final StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();


            marshaller.marshal(element, stringWriter);
          String message = stringWriter.toString();
```

This will give you desired output.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is implementation dependant. I stumbled into opposite problem (I needed self-closing tag) and I resolved in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158723/write-empty-tag-with-jaxb-and-xmlstreamwriter) way.
You can try using [this version of `marshal()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#marshal(java.lang.Object,%20javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter)) or modifying code from linked answer.

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved,
To force a closing tag, just add an empty String as the value of this tag !
You can do it using @XmlValue :

```
public class closedTag {

    @XmlValue
    private String content;


    public closedTag() {
        this.content = "";
    }

}
```