# JAXB : Xml tags when empty

Tags: java, jaxb

Using JAXB i am marshalling My Custom object into Xml.

Consider a Object like this :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Config")
public class Config {

    @XmlElement(name = "projectVersion")
    private String version;
```

if value of version is null then i am manually setting it in setter.

```
this.version=version==null?"":version;
```

but then i am getting the tag output like :

```
</version>
```

but customer demands the output like

> `<version></version>`

How can i achieve it ? other than setting empty space " " in setter method ?

Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32448868/how-to-generate-end-tag-for-empty-elelemt-in-xml-using-jaxb) might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Why does your customer demand it? For what reason?

`<version/>` and `<version></version>` are strictly equivalent. These are both empty elements, period.

Since from the spec point of view these two syntaxes are equivalent, this is purely inplementation-dependent. Try marshalling to `new IndentingXMLStreamWriter(file)` and/or setting `marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE)` on the marshaller.